# How to install apesmit python package?

Tags: python, pypi

I tried to install apesmit from PyPi ( pip install apesmit ). But I'm getting error `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement apesmit (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for apesmit`
Could you help me to do this?

Comment: Pleas add the exact command you're using. Also, which version of pip is this (`pip --version`)? Try updating it (`pip install -U pip`) and run the command again.

Comment: I'm using pip 9.0.1. I have tried pip install apesmit for installing apesmith.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have followed these steps to install apesmith

1. `sudo wget http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/apesmit/dist/apesmit-0.01.tar.gz`
2. `tar xzf apesmit-0.01.tar.gz.`
3. `sudo nano apesmit-0.01/distribute_setup.py`
   change DEFAULT_URL to "https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/" in distribute_setup.py
4. `pip install /full path/apesmit-0.01`

Answer (score 0):

Because the author hasn't uploaded any packages yet and there is nothing to download. The list of packages at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/apesmit or https://pypi.python.org/simple/apesmit/ is empty.

Comment: Text is there but the list of packages is empty. Compare for example with https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Cheetah3